# Asp.Net Core 2.0-2.2 Kestrel not serving static content

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, .net-core

When running a Asp.Net Core 2.0 (or 2.2) app using IIS express, static files (css, js) are served as expected.  However when using command line/Kestrel via "dotnet publish -o [targetDirectory]" and dotnet [website.dll], Kestrel does not serve up any static content. Utilizing browser F12, I see Kestrel returns a 404 error. Looking closer, when entering the file path directly in the browser (localhost:5000/**css**/cssfile.css) the file is not displayed but *the browser appears to redirect to "localhost:5000/cssfile.css"* but still returns a 404 error (note the missing /css/ directory).

I created this project via Visual Studio 2017, and chose the defaults for a new MVC Core 2.0 application (SDK was installed).

I have followed the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files) to enable static files in the program.cs and startup.cs files. These implement "app.UseStaticFiles();" and ".UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())". None of the articles found via google seem to help. I have verified dotnet copied the static content to the target directory.

What am I missing?  Thanks

```
// Program.cs
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost
   .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   .UseStartup<Startup>()
   .Build();

// Startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/HandleError");
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute( name: "default", template: "{controller=User}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the file located relative to the content root? The default would be `wwwroot/css/cssfile.css` in your case AFAIK

Comment: That is correct, the file is located at wwwroot/css/cssfile.css

Comment: What does `ConfigurationHelper.Configure(Configuration)` do? Also, if the app actually sends a redirect, what do the logs say? Turn on verbose logging to see everything that is going on.

Comment: ConfigurationHelper is a custom library, I will confirm but I don't think that is the issue based on other tests without that line.

Comment: The shared layout.cshtml utilizes "<environment names="..."> to add different css/js files based on the environment. The correct links and scripts are added when Environment="Development". When deploying on Kestrel, the Environment is not set. How do I set environment variables for kestrel? I  do not see how to set those using Web.Config or launchSettings.json >>when running on Kestrel<<.

Comment: This is controlled through the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT. To set it in command line (cmd) use "set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development".

Comment: Setting the environmental variables is not recommended in production. One thing that i noticed is, i was missing minified version(.min.js) of the same file. I manually updated my bundlecofig.json with the missing files and it worked file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce your error using a fresh ASP.NET Core 2.0 project following these steps;

1. <kbd>md static-test</kbd>
2. <kbd>cd static-test</kbd>
3. <kbd>dotnet new web</kbd>
4. Add folder `css` in wwwroot.
5. Add file `site.css` in `wwwroot/css`.
6. Insert `app.UseStaticFiles();` at the start of `Startup.Configure()` method.
7. <kbd>dotnet publish -o pubweb</kbd>
8. <kbd>cd pubweb</kbd>
9. <kbd>dotnet .\static-test.dll</kbd>
10. Access http://localhost:5000/css/site.css using browser.

`dotnet.exe` renders the following output in my terminal:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\src\static-test\pubweb
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/css/site.css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/css/site.css'. Physical path: 'C:\src\static-test\pubweb\wwwroot\css\site.css'
```

As you can see it will successfully serve the css file within a subfolder correctly. Please try the above steps and compare the code and output with your failing project. If it is still failing, please attach the debug info on `Request` vs. `Physical` path from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware` above.

Comment: I followed those steps and id did correctly serve the css file.  I my case I created the MVC Core 2.0 project via VS, although I did add some dependencies to other VS projects.  I am going through and comparing the differences now.

Comment: Looking closer, when using the browser F12, it appears the page is not asking for all of the static files when run from Kestrel rather than IIS express. For example, the page served from IIS express asks for core.min.js, but the page served from Kestrel does not. Perhaps something in the config/view model is configured to make the page request different content??  Investigating further...

Comment: You seem to have a lot of other dependencies in your project that you did not explain in your question..

Comment: For anyone still scratching their heads: Note that he's running the dotnet command *in the same folder* as `wwwroot`. If you skip step 8 and change 9 to `dotnet .\pubweb\static-test.dll` it won't work. This is easy to trip on when you're doing a Docker build. See my answer for more details

Comment: So im running a little side project on a raspberry pi, and I was having this issue on and off but could not figure out why. @SpencerRuport sparked an idea, I changed directory to the folder that contained my binary file on linux, and ran it there and it worked. If I run it from above that folder then it does not load the static wwwroot files. Not sure why its doing this though.

Comment: The key thing here is to hit the `dotnet xxxx.dll` command from the directory where `wwwroot` folder is present

Answer (score 24):

I tried so many useless things, this was the fix for me:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseKestrel()
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.UseIISIntegration()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseWebRoot("E:\\xyz\\wwwroot")
.UseUrls("http://localhost:5050")
    .Build();
```

Serving static files started working as soon as I added:

```
.UseWebRoot("E:\\xyz\\wwwroot")
```

<sub>I got a conflict on one of my services running on port 5000, so I specified to start on port 5050.</sub>

---

**Update for .Net Core 2.2**

For .NET Core 2.2, the following works: `.UseWebRoot("wwwroot")`

However, a more readable and explicit approach to get the path:

`static string webRoot = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot");`

and then
`UseWebRoot(webRoot);`

Comment: Tested on .NET Core 2.1, after applied .UseWebRoot(@"C:\xxx\xxx\wwwroot"), the browser can load images, js, css, etc... Thanks.

Comment: This was the fix for me. As well as a little fiddling to get a linux friendly path without hardcoding it :)

Comment: for .NET Core 2.2, I had to add .UseWebRoot("wwwroot")

Comment: I'd like to add onto this how you can dynamically get the path

``static string webRoot = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot");``
and then 
``UseWebRoot(webRoot);``

Comment: I'm using .NET Core v3.1 and this extension doesn't appear to exist?

Comment: I'm also on 3.1 so it doesn't work for me.  Why do they keep subtly changing it?

Answer (score 10):

For me, the problem was the working directory. I wasn't paying attention to the directory I was in when trying to launch the app with `dotnet /var/www/project/project.dll`. It automatically uses your current directory as the working directory when you launch the app this way.

I realized this when I looked at a `.service` file for another project, which has the WorkingDirectory specified:

```
...
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/project/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/project/project.dll
...
```

So, either make sure you are in the correct directory when you run your project, or ensure that the WorkingDirectory is properly set in your `.service` file.

Comment: Your answer helped me - I use Supervisor to keep my Kestrel running - the 2nd line needs to match the third line directory.

[program:MyApp]
command=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/MyApp.dll
directory=/var/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myapp.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapp.out.log
environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
user=www-data
stopsignal=INT

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a very similar issue. I couldn't get Kestrel to serve up any static content; I had a config that worked fine in .net core 1.1, but it wouldn't work in .net core 2.0.

I debugged through it and the IFileProvider instance used by the static file middleware was NullFileProvider. I had to do this in Startup.cs to get static content served:

```
app.UseFileServer(
    new FileServerOptions() {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("some_path")
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error I realized that once I begin using Kestrel, the static files web root is suddenly mapped to the bin folder instead of the development folder.  To fix this you can do one of two things.

1. You can set all of the static files you want to include to Copy to Output Directory
2. You can remap the root directory to a certain path:

   ```
   .UseKestrel(...)
   .UseWebRoot(@"C:\MyProject\wwwroot\");
   ```

I use the wwwroot folder that I develop in so I don't have to ensure all new items get added to Copy to Output Directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have create an new project with asp.net core **2.1** (MVC) with the MS template and then have included a css file **animate.css** with some animations.

To be able to use it, a **href** has to be added in **_Layout.cshtml**
Thereby, I have noted, that MS has "forgotten" to add the environments **"Staging" and "Production"**
So.. if the href is added in the "Development" environment, everything works fine in debugging (IIS Express), but it don't works with a selfhost (and I assume also not on "the real" IIS), as this is **not** the Development environment and the hrefs's are **not** set at runtime.
Therefore I have copy -pasted the "Development" environment also for "Staging" and "Production" (see snipped below).

```
  <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/animate.css">
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>

    @*<environment include="Staging,Production"> -> was missing completely!copy pasted from Development*@
    <environment include="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/animate.css">
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    @*End manually inserted*@
```

Comment: No, you have this wrong. Check generated HTML. The exclude="Development" will execute for Staging and Production, and properly use Bootstrap stylesheet from CDN instead of loading directly from the web server and pick the minified version of site.css. If you want your "animate.css" to load in all environments, put it outside of the environment tags. Please read the fundamentals here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1):

If you're running into this in Docker you need to know that the "root" is based on where you're executing the `dotnet` command. I'm not sure this makes the most sense, but it is what it is. Where it's easy to get tripped up is you need to make sure your Docker container is in the correct directory before executing the command.

```
WORKDIR /app
# Example publish/build command:
RUN dotnet publish -o out
# Your publish folder is /app/out so...
# ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/out/myapp.dll"]
# will run but you'll get 404s on all your static content. 
# Instead use:
WORKDIR /app/out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

Don't use my script as an example of a proper Docker publish script. It's just an example.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. (I developed in Win and hosted on Linux, in case it makes a difference). Just a few files worked (mostly default ones), but my own content caused 404.

The culprit was: **capitals in file and folder names didn't work for me**.
Converted everything to lower case and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in .NET Core 2.2 MVC, running it as self-contained windows service with "Local system" user.

The problem is that windows services use default directory in "C:\Windows\System32", so you need to define new path:

```
.UseWebRoot(@"C:\MyProject\wwwroot\");
```

Here is code I use for detecting path in runtime:

```
// Find app directory.
var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));
var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
if (isService)
{
    var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
}

// Configure web host
var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(currentDir)
        .UseWebRoot(Path.Combine(currentDir, "wwwroot"));
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

// Run.
if (isService)
{
    host.RunAsService();
}
else
{
    host.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether those static files are present within the below tags.

```
<environment include="Development">
</environment>
```

As you have Published, if the static files are present inside the `include Development`, then they will not be present in the **Published** folder. Also, Check `View Source` and see whether those links are present or not.

Comment: OP tested the direct URL to the file and that didn’t work. This has nothing to do with MVC views.