# asp.net core not loading static files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have an app .NET core 2.1 with this code:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Assets")),
            RequestPath = "/Assets"
        });
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

and my structure folder:

[image]

but none of these urls open the image:

"my-website.com/images/snes/alien.jpg"

"my-website.com/wwwroot/images/snes/alien.jpg"

"my-website.com/Assets/Snes/alien.jpg"

anybody know what is wrong?

Edit: Here is the folder get by CurrentDirectoy() method (apparently is correct):

[image]

Edit2: With this code work on localhost but not when i publish on azure:

```
 app.UseFileServer(
        new FileServerOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot"))
        });
```

Comment: what is your current working directory?

Comment: Can you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47385434/495455

Comment: How did you publish to Azure? Fail to reproduce your issue, this `"my-website.com/Assets/Snes/alien.jpg"` should be able to open this image. Did you get 404 error or anything else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are most likely in a working directory that is different than the one you think. Please check this by setting a breakpoint on foo:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var foo = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
}
```

The solution depends in how you start the application.

If you are doing it via Visual Studio, probably you have set another Working Directory in the Project properties?

[image: Project Properties]

If via command line, you need to `cd` to your project root.

Another solution, would be to use the [directory of your assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52797/2441442):

```
// get the directory
var assemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
var assetDirectory = Path.Combine(assemblyDirectory, "Assets"));

// use it
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(assetDirectory),
    RequestPath = "/Assets"
});
```

Comment: apparently the working directory is correct. It is one level above the "wwwroot" folder. 
I edited the post, look the image.

Comment: This solution works.  wwwroot is finnicky for me.  In my case, it's best for outside generated content to be served from a different root directory then wwwroot

Answer (score 6):

use `IHostingEnvironment`

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
     FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Assets")),
            RequestPath = "/Assets"
});
```

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and this worked best for me.

Comment: worked net core 8

Answer (score 6):

If you are using visual code then you have to set up your working directory in `cwd` parameter of `configuration` array of your `lunch.json` file. See attached screenshot.

[image]